# URL Rewriting .php to .html

Tags: php, html, url, url-rewriting

I'm converting my urls extension from `.php` to `.html` in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.).php
RewriteRule ^(.*).php $1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html $1.php [L] 
FallbackResource /index.php
```

The problem is that I have some section with the word "php" on it:

```
www.mywebsite.com/phpscripts.php
```

And when it is converted:

```
www.mywebsite.com/htmlscripts.html
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*).php
```

This regex says: *anything, including nothing, followed by a single arbitrary character, followed by "php"*. For example, it'll match "blahphp.html", specifically it'll match the "blahphp" part and not care about the extension at all.

What you're looking for is this:

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ $1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

`(.+)\.php$` is *something (at least one character) followed by a period followed by "php" **at the end of the string***. You can also get rid of the `RewriteCond`, it doesn't add anything to these rules.

Also note that you should be changing all your HTML files to link to `href="...html"`. Don't rely on these redirects alone to fix your problem; not only is it inefficient to redirect every single request, it'll also break POST requests. It's only acceptable to redirect clients which try to open the old URLs for whatever reason to the new canonical URLs.

Comment: Doesn't work (Redirection LOOP ) RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /    
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ $1.html [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (.+)\.html$ $1.php [L] 
FallbackResource /index.php

Comment: I analyse it with redirectdetctive : It redirects to www.mywebsite.com/phpscripts.html many times, so the first problem is solved but how to deal with the loop

Comment: Crank up the Apache debugging level and analyse the rewriting process in the Apache log, if that's something you have access to.

Comment: Honestly I don't know how to do this, the problem could be from flags ? and don't understand difference between internal and external redirection